# phpinfo does not show redis but php -m does, mac os

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

I just installed phpredis on my mac and when I do

```
$ php -m
```

I see

```
PHP Modules]
bcmath
....
redis
Reflection
.....
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

But in my phpinfo I do not see that information.

I have 
cd /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-redis.ini with

```
[redis]
extension="/usr/local/opt/php55-redis/redis.so"
```

php -i shows the following

```
redis

Redis Support => enabled
Redis Version => 2.2.6

Reflection

Reflection => enabled
Version => $Id: 95b780d3f0d017feba96a5c35cca9541186114ad $

session

Session Support => enabled
Registered save handlers => files user redis
```

What am I missing here

thanks

Comment: Different SAPIs used with command line and *phpinfo()* examples? Have you tried `php -i`? Does *phpinfo()* show this config file being processed at all?

Comment: I tried php -i and it show redis. I will update my question with that info

Answer (score 1):

ok I found out what was going on.

I had to copy the default ini file in /etc to /etc/php.ini

and then I add this in the /etc/php.ini

extension="/usr/local/opt/php55-redis/redis.so"

and restarted the webserver and I was able to see redis now.

All good!

Comment: Did this same thing but redis still doesn't show up in phpinfo() and when I create an instance of the Redis class, I get the error 'Class Redis could not be found in /path/to/file.php' what am in missing. I have restarted, stopped and start the server (apache) several times.